# Session holding Big List

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application which has multilingual support. Almost every word has multilingual support and at each page request I get all the words in the currently selected language from the database into a `List` and I use it for each `Word`: I hold `MeaningID` for each element and print out the matched one from the `List`. Costly approach, but better than reaching to database for every `Word`.

Still, I wonder if there's a data structure I can use globally throughout the project, which is only loaded from the database when the user changes the selected language. Is there a session like list structure can I use for such a purpose?

**EDIT:** To make things clearer I'm posting my database tables.

```
 --Word--           --WordBase--          --Language--
  ID                   ID                    ID
  Text                 Text                  Name
  BaseID
  LanguageID
```

As it's seen, `WordBase`s are meanings that `Word`s depend on by a `Language`. Example data is:

```
--Word--             --Base--             --Language--
1;Hallo;1;1          1;Hello              1-Deutsch
2;Hello;1;2          2;Good               2-English
3;Gut;  2;1
4;Good; 2;2
```

Comment: I would take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part

Comment: there are no limits for words, meanings and languages in my application. user should only press the language in the mainscreen and use it that way. and throughout the usage of the project I add the words automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cache this using `Cache`. Then, you can manage the `Cache` to hold the information during the user session or by time expiration.

Take a look here: [Walkthrough: Caching Application Data in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your web app is like a dictionary? I mean... your "words" are the data of your application... or are you talking about internationalization?

If it is internationalization, I think there are better ways to do it... using the tools built in. Check this: http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

If the translatable data is too large... may be you could have an hybrid approach... keeping tokens in database... and translation in resource files.  Then, caching would be useful, specially if your data doesn't change very often (you can set caching for 30min... and for that time you avoid SQL queries to retrieve words in every request).

Comment: I have changeable meanings after words. I cannot use simple internationalization. The language count and meaning count is dynamic. I just need a data structure I can use in whole project.